# Excel columns, openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, automation, openpyxl

I have made a program that uses `openpyxl` and I am trying to look for a program that translate column numbers to the respective letters e.g.:

```
>>> _get_exl_base26(1)
A
>>> _get_exl_base26(676)
ZZ
>>> etc.
```

Is this possible?

I tried using `int(n + 10, base = 36)` but for the multi-digited columns, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openpyxl already has a function, called `get_column_letter`, which converts a column number to a letter. Here is the code:

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
# Change n to the column number
n = 1
print(get_column_letter(n))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @DapperDuck for letting me know!

Comment: @Leo No problem! If my answer solved your question, you can mark it as **accepted** by clicking the checkmark near my answer!

Comment: Sure I clicked it! Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! Good luck with your program!

Comment: I would need to see the rest of the the code. If you want, you can post this separately as  another question and elaborate on it. I can click your profile and help you there!

Comment: By the way, sorry to be a bit demanding, but do you know what's wrong with this line?  `cll` is the tuple I used to save the cell coordinates:

```_ = ws.cell(column == get_column_letter(cll[0][0]), row == (cll[0][1]), value == cll[1])```

Comment: Sure @DapperDuck